# Include aar in sbt build

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I have an android project here that includes local file aars in gradle via

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':packagename_0.3')
}
```

I am unable to translate that to the appropriate sbt syntax so that during the build sbt is actually able to resolve the dependencies. Does anyone have an idea ? I checked [scala on android](https://scala-on-android.taig.io/dependencies/) but still did not manage to find a working way. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up extracting the jars from the aars and adding them to the default unmanagedBase folder (*src/main/libs*).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a setting:

```
localAars += path_to_aar_file
```